# A simple .NET messaging system

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I am trying to create a system to send messages between components in `C#` (using the `Mono` runtime). Here is some pseudo-code of what I am trying to achieve in terms of functionality:

**Creating the Message**

```
MyMessage : BaseMessage {}
AnotherMessage : BaseMessage { string data; }
```

**Subscribing**

```
MyMessage.Subscribe(MyMessageHandler)
AnotherMessage.Subscribe(AnotherMessageHandler)
```

**Message Handlers**

```
void MyMessageHandler(MyMessage message)
{
    // code
}

void AnotherMessageHandler(AnotherMessage message)
{
    // code
}
```

**Sending the Message**

```
MyMessage.Send(MyMessageInstance);
AnotherMessage.Send(AnotherMessageInstance);
```

**Additional Information**

Each message handler will only take one type of message, and that message may or may not have a payload of any type (for example a string called data).

---

I have a working solution in `C++` (see below for the subscribing part):

```
// A function-style macro is used to call this method
template <typename Type, typename Caller>
void subscribe(boost::function<void(const Type&)> subscriber, boost::shared_ptr<Caller> caller)
{
    m_subscriptions[typeid(Type)].connect(Subscribers::slot_type([subscriber](const BaseMessage& message)
    {
            subscriber(static_cast<const Type&>(message));
    }).track(caller));
}
```

For those not familiar with `boost::signals2`, `.track` creates a weak pointer to the caller and disconnects the subscriber when it is destroyed.

---

I am aiming for something similar in `C#`, but am struggling to do so. This is what I have so far:

```
abstract class Message<MessageArgType>
{
    public delegate void Handler(MessageArgType arg);
    private event Handler subscribers;

    public void Subscribe(Handler subscriber)
    {
        subscribers += subscriber;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Handler subscriber)
    {
        subscribers -= subscriber;
    }

    public void Send(MessageArgType arg)
    {
        subscribers.Invoke(arg);
    }
}
```

It seems to me that this will store a **strong** reference to the object that the message handler belongs to. After a lot of googling, I ended up finding [this](http://diditwith.net/2007/03/23/SolvingTheProblemWithEventsWeakEventHandlers.aspx). However, as someone quite new to `C#`, I found this quite difficult to grasp what was going on. Also, this post was made in 2007, so there may be a better solution now, but I am struggling to find one.

---

**To conclude**

Could someone please provide me with some guidance on how to get a weak reference from a delegate in a thread-safe (due to the GC running on another thread) manner that can achieve an interface similar to the pseudo code above?

Comment: There's another implementation here that seems simpler: http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/08/event_subscription_using_weak_references.html

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch thank you, I shall give it a read now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case of "No matter how much you know, there's always plenty more", I did some more research and discovered that .NET 3 added the `WeakEventManager` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850(v=vs.110).aspx

To use the Generic `WeakEventManager` class, do this:

```
WeakEventManager<EventSource, SomeEventEventArgs>
    .AddHandler(source, "SomeEvent", source_SomeEvent);
```

EDIT:

In your case, you would probably do something like this:

```
public void Subscribe(Handler subscriber)
{
     WeakEventManager<Message, MessageArgType>
         .AddHandler(this, "subscribers", subscriber);
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was hoping for, thank you! I'll give it a try and mark this as a solution if it works (I can't see why it wouldn't though)

Comment: Going through this, I'm not quite sure what the `source` should be when I add a handler? I'm excepting anything to be the `source` of the message.

Comment: @OMGtechy - the source is the object that raises the event.  So, for instance, if it's a timer.. you pass the timer instance, the name of the event, and the delegate that handles it.  This isn't the source of the message, this is the object that raises the event.